# Convert varchar to bigInt including null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get all the values which exist in one table and not the other. The condition to join them is varchar in one table and bigInt in the other (swmItems is bigInt, OBJ_TAB is varchar). I tried the following:

```
 SELECT si.upc as upc from swmItems si 
 left outer join dbo.OBJ_TAB obj  on cast(obj.F01 as BIGINT) = si.upc 
 WHERE obj.F01 IS NULL
```

however it gives me the error: "Error converting data type varchar to bigint".

I also tried the following:

```
 SELECT * FROM OBJ_TAB WHERE ISNUMERIC(f01) != 1
```

And it return nothing so all my values should be numbers in OBJ_TAB

I think it's because of the values exist in the first table and not the second (trying to convert null to bigInt). Is there anyway to join the two tables this way?

I am using Microsoft SQL 2012

Footnote: In OBJ_TAB there exist number of zeros in front of the numbers that's why comparing everything as varchar doesn't work for me.

Comment: And what is the datatype of `upc`?

Comment: upc: bigInt, F01: varchar

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers a question that nobody has ever wanted to ask - if you're wanting to find rows that can't be converted to `bigint`, you probably just want rows that contain anything other than digits. Try `SELECT * FROM OBJ_TAB WHERE f01 LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` to find the problem rows.

Comment: I found bunch of other non integer values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT swmItems.upc
FROM swmItems 
     LEFT JOIN OBJ_TAB
         ON CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(OBJ_TAB.F01 + '.e0') = 1 -- ensure no decimals
                 THEN CASE WHEN CONVERT(float, OBJ_TAB.F01) BETWEEN -9223372036854775808 
                                                                AND 9223372036854775807
                           THEN CONVERT(bigint, OBJ_TAB.F01)
                      END
            END = swmItems.upc
WHERE OBJ_TAB.F01 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert any non-numeric value into integer datatype. but you can convert numeric value into varchar datatype.

So, you can try like this.

```
SELECT si.upc as upc from swmItems si 
left outer join dbo.OBJ_TAB obj  on obj.F01 = Cast(si.upc As Varchar)
WHERE obj.F01 IS NULL
```

Comment: True however as I said in the question the F01 format is something like: '00090001' and the upc is: 90001,  varchar for these two values wouldn't be the same then

Comment: You can add zeros befor the number. Right( '00000000' + Cast(si.upc As Varchar),8)

Comment: Yea but I don't know how many. The total number of digits should be 13. so if my number is 1 then I need to add 12 zeros at the beginning and if the number is 3333333 then I just add 6 zeros

Comment: As I have told you. You just need to add number of fixed length zeros in `Right` function. ie. `Right( '0000000000000' + Cast(si.upc As Varchar),13)`

Answer (score 0):

Long dead thread, but if you're coming upon it from the future like I did, give [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) a shot.